# Print data from two line to another file using loop

Tags: linux, shell

I have a file where I want to print data to another file except first line data

**Data in the list.txt is**

```
Vik
Ram 
Raj
Pooja 
OFA
JAL
```

**Output should be into new file => fd.txt like this below except first line data 'VIK'**

```
Ram 
Raj
Pooja 
OFA
JAL
```

**Code not working**

```
find $_filepath -type d > list.txt

for i in 2 3 4 5 .. N
do
    echo $i
done<list.txt >>fd.txt
```

Comment: `awk NR>1  list.txt` is enough to print the file except 1st line.

Answer (score 1):

tail -n+2 outputs the last lines starting from the second one.
from https://superuser.com/questions/1071448/tail-head-all-line-except-x-last-first-lines